# Publish web vb.net in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, filesystems, publish

**I have a VB.net website. I develop it use Studio 2013 and Devexpress 14.1 :**
[image: Solution Visual Studio 2013]

**Now, I wanna publish this solution to file system, then I will copy it to sever.

I choose publish :**
[image: Choose Publish Website]

**Create Profile :**
[image: Enter Profile name]

**Choose File System :**
[image: Choose method]

**The configuration is only : Debug :**
[image]

**And I publish.**
**But the publish source I have is nochange compare with original source. No app code (.dll) , no Devexpress dll include. And I cannot use it to publish to sever.

Please tell me how to publish web file system in this case ?

Thanks**

Comment: Did you find solution of this. I am facing exactly same problem.

Comment: No. I must make a new website application project, copy website project to website application project then publish it :(